# Why does Trax automatically create a Serial layer over a sublayer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, trax

I implemented a Serial Layer in [Trax](https://github.com/google/trax) (deep learning library by Google). Why does an additional Serial layer is created in spite of already declaring one?

Below is the code.

```
model = tl.Serial(
        tl.Dense(n_units=512),
        tl.Relu()
        )
print(model)
```

The output is:

```
Serial[
  Dense_512
  Serial[
     Relu
  ]

]
```

While it should have been

```
Serial[
  Dense_512
  Relu
]
```